# How to read API secured with username and password in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an API that is secured with username and password. I'm using ASP.NET Core MVC but I'm reading the API using JavaScript. Now my organization secured this API with username and password and I want to know how can I read the API with these username and password using C# because it's more secure than JavaScript. What code I can Add in my Post request in the controller. If you can guide me to a way to achieve this.

I found this way but it's not supported in ASP.NET Core:

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(@"https://sub.domain.com/api/operations?param=value&param2=value");
req.Method = "GET";
req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + 
Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("username:password"));
//req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Comment: Was the problem resolved?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I don't know why my comments were deleted. But yes I used the code below and had to change a little bit in it. I used `IHttpClientFactory` and called the API from button click in JS instead of calling it from the `HttpPost` from the controller and It worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for net core it is better to use http client

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var baseAddress = "https://sub.domain.com";

    var api = "/api/operations?param=value&param2=value";
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);

    var authenticationString = $"{username}:{password}";
    var base64EncodedAuthenticationString = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authenticationString));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64EncodedAuthenticationString);
            
    var response = await client.GetAsync(api);
    var statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var stringData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(stringData);
    }
}
```

UPDATE

If you wont to use http client but use ajax too, just create an action with the code above and call this action from ajax.

Comment: Don't dispose of the `HttpClient` instance: [You're using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/); [You're (probably still) using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://josef.codes/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/)

Comment: Better to inject the `IHttpClientFactory` service and use that: [Make HTTP requests using IHttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: @RichardDeeming Thanks for advises. I could even offer  using a named or typed client.  But it will be good if this post will be used at all.  I give 99% that  I will not get any response  from PO . What makes sense to talk about the factories?